# The bootstrap breakpoint doesn't work well with ejs

Tags: express, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am currently working on a node app using express, and rendering html page using ejs.

When I used bootstrap in my `.ejs`file, the `.col-xs-*, .col-sm-*` breakpoints worked well, but the breakpoints for the larger width cannot work as expected.

While I used bootstrap in the  `.html` file and  opened it in the browser, all breakpoints worked fine. And I've tried include bootstrap from both CDN and local, it resulted in the same situation. Can't figure what went wrong.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">   
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/bootstrap.min.css'>     
        <title>
            TEST
        </title>
        <style>
            .eight{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .four{
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class='container-fluid'>
        <article class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-8 eight'>
                8
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4 four'>
                4
            </div>
        </article>            
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the red div to occupy three-fourths of the row, the blue one occupy the rest.

Suggestions and solutions to the problem are appreciated.(Not a native English speaker, sorry for the unclear expression if any.)

Comment: Does changing element "article" as "div" do any effect?

Comment: @AtishShakya  No, the problem still exists.I have tried to use only `div` as the elements applying bootstrap class, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Btw what exactly is your problem ? Does using col-sm-8 not set it to 8th part of full width or what?

Comment: Also try remove the container-fluid from body class and see result

Comment: @AtishShakya I want to use `col-lg-8` to set it to the 8th part, but it didn't work. Same for `col-md-8`.It just moved to the next row.But `col-sm-8` worked.And what I mentioned above are the situation when I use express with ejs  to render the web page.While I use the plain html and apply `col-lg-8`, `col-md-8`, `col-sm-8` then open it via browser, they all worked.Same code but it results differently.